# Lightswitch HTML - Table filter where not null

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

When you create a browse screen and add a table control on, you can filter it down to find specific's, however eliminating null values is not one of the basic options, please could someone point me in the direction of how I can achieve this or if this even possible?

Example:
[image]

When the "`EstTravelFromSite`" is null, I would like the table not to show this result.

can I achieve this on this screen or by entering some JS code on the table?

Thankyou for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lightswitch will give you the options "is null" or "is not null" if the column you're filtering on is a nullable datatype. If you're using the Lightswitch table designer to create your data models, Lightswitch will expose any column which isn't marked Required as a nullable data type (oversimplification but sufficient here). So check your data definitions.

Table designer showing required and not required (implicitly nullable) integer properties.
[image: Table designer showing required and not required (implicitly nullable) integer properties]

Screen query filter for a nullable property
[image: Screen query filter for a nullable property]

Screen query filter for a required property
[image: Screen query filter for a required property]

The other alternative if that won't work in your design is to create a query (right click on the table and select Add Query) then add code to filter out records with nulls (Write Code -> Query1_PreProcessQuery). Because this is happening on the server side, the code will be VB or c# depending on how your project was created. Then use the query rather than the table as the source for the screen.

Comment: do you have a printscreen of this option, or a particular datatype this works on as i cannot find this option anywhere myself... and tahnkyou for the answer

Comment: I've added some screenshots showing it working on an integer. Is that what you meant?

Comment: thanks for the printscreens, get it now :) and have the null option myself now